# Could not resolve properties placeholder, when the properties internally have a placeholders

Tags: spring

I ve a properties file -

application.properties (content as below)

```
core.microsite=q=MarketId:${marketId}&q=PresaleOff
```

Here is my spring config xml -

```
<bean id="myBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/application.properties" />
     </bean>

<bean id="MyQueryBuilder" class="com.search.builder.impl.MyQueryBuilder">
        <property name="queryTemplateMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="microsite" value="${core.microsite}" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now on server startup (tomocat) I get this exception -

```
ug 29, 2012 11:50:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'MyQueryBuilder' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/my-service/WEB-INF/lib/my-app-1.0.2.RC8-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/config/app-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'marketId'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
```

It clearly fails because core.microsite property has internally has one more placeholder **${marketId}**

How to resolve this problem?

Setting the "ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" to true should work (theoretically). Not sure what to do now?

Appreciate any pointers!

Thanks.

Comment: When using `${core.microsite}` in your applicationContext, do you want the `${marketId}` get substitute for example `q=MarketId:12345&q=PresaleOff`, or remain as `q=MarketId:${marketId}&q=PresaleOff`?

Comment: I want that value remain as is. That is - q=MarketId:${marketId}&q=PresaleOff

Comment: Try using escape character in the properties file `core.microsite=q=MarketId:\$\{marketId\}&q=PresaleOff`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure about the root cause of the error, but can recommend a few workarounds :

**Workaround 1**: Change the prefix of the placeholder this way:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/application.properties"/>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="%{"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="MyQueryBuilder" class="com.search.builder.impl.MyQueryBuilder">
    <property name="queryTemplateMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="microsite" value="%{core.microsite}" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Workaround 2**: If you absolutely need to have your property value have the $, then temporarily change the ${marketId} to something else say %{marketId}, have a `@PostConstruct` on your MyQueryBuilder where you look at the map entries and find and replace all occurences of %{marketId} with ${marketId}